# Node.js: encrypt field with key from aws

Tags: mysql, node.js, security, encryption, adonis.js

I'm developing in Adonis.js 4 (node.js).

What I want to accomplish is to save inside my database an encrypted value. But I don't want to encrypt that value with an app key (same key for all values). I would like to have something external (this is why of AWS) where I can store an id and a key for each of my values.

Let's say I have a user table, where I have a password field. I want the password to be encrypted with a different key for each user, so that if someone has access to my db and one key they still could have access only to one user account.

Do you know some easy way I could achieve this?

From my researches I think I should use this for keeping secrets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SecretsManager.html

But what about Adonis? How could I change encryption key dynamically?

Comment: If you encrypt something and you need access to the unencrypted value then you need to store the key close for decryption. An application still has access to all secrets in the secret manager when it has that permission. A secret manager simply enables you to quickly change secret centrally when you suspect a breach. Either way, passwords that are used to authenticate your users should not be encrypted. They have to hashed repeatedly with a high work factor. Have a look at Argon2, scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: Passwords shouldn't be reversible so encryption is the wrong paradigm. With any aspect of online access to encrypted data consider who has the access to the key and where is the protection to ensure that only the authorized users have access. This is a hard problem. See [OWASP Password storage cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#password-storage-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for you  to store a hash of the pasword with a high factor(with salt) and then the encrypt you data key with a KDF on the password.So with a password you can get only one data key to use?

Comment: Would it change all the discussion if I told you that my goal is to store this way a custodial wallet? So encrypt/hash the private key.